# WordPress API have Plugin Anti-piracy feature?

Tags: wordpress

Does the WordPress Plugin API feature any anti-piracy API/functionality? Or is this something developers need to role on their own?

Comment: Are you talking about the Wordpress API exposing your data to the outside world?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The WordPress developer community generally does not approve of plugins and themes which are not distributed under free licenses. In fact, [all WordPress plugins distributed through the WordPress Plugin Directory must be licensed under GPLv2 or later](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#the-guidelines), and [**all** WordPress themes which are distributed are required to be licensed under the GPL, or a GPL-compatible license](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/wordpress-licensing-the-gpl/).

As such, WordPress does not provide any support for licensing of non-free plugins or themes. You're on your own.

Comment: the purpose of my asking, is, how do companies who sell plugins protect against illegal copy and distribution of their plugin? Because anyone can go in and copy the plugin folder/zip and send it to another server running WordPress - ie pirate plugins. Do most plugin developers just not code for this at all?

Comment: Every plugin developer must implement their own solution for this. Many developers who attempt to do so end up implementing something that 1) is easily defeated; 2) harms site performance; and/or 3) creates a security vulnerability. My advice: distribute your plugin under the GPL.